# Azure storage plugin in jenkins create folder structure on azure blob

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

I'm having my Jenkins freestyle job which builds and deploy the angular project on azure blob storage.
Everything worked fine, but when a job succeeded, it creates a full folder structure on the blob.

Because my angular project build is in a subfolder. I provide a full path to the files which I need in my azure blob.
[Jenkins post-build action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGwXA.png)
and it gives me directory structure in the azure blob.
[Azure blob storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9SGt.png)

I need my angular build files(assets, js, etc.) directly in the $web blob.
[Actual requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95pz4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug of windows azure storage Jenkins plugin which is maintained by Visual Studio China Jenkins Team as mentioned [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-azure-storage). So may be report bug or feature request as instructed [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-azure-storage-plugin#reporting-bugs-and-feature-requests).

As a workaround you may try [Azure CLI Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-cli) and accomplish your requirement by using [az storage blob upload-batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch) Azure CLI command in your Jenkins job or you may also try with AzCopy utility as well. (or) If you use Jenkins pipeline then you can do something like below. So overall it's like not a good solution for freestyle job but better approach via pipeline job.

```
dir(‘AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\EEE\’) {
    azureUpload … filesPath: 'files'…
}
```

Hope this helps!!